# Do inode values have any effect on performance?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, inode

I recently saved 7 files to two separate directories (I will call A and B). Out of curiosity I used Ubuntu's ls -i command and found files in each directory had consecutive inodes. I then noticed that I had mistakenly saved one of these files in A while it should have been saved in B and moved it thus. Using ls -i again I found the inodes were unchanged. If an application were to read from and write to every file from B would this difference in inode vales affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. The inode information is just that - info. Each inode stores the attributes and disk block location(s) of the object's data. Reading and writing to files will update some of the inode info, but that is irrespective of what the info was previously.

Edit: I was considering SSDs. It is possible there could be a Very Minimal seek overhead on an older magnetic disk.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking more about the latter case of using a disk.

Comment: You're very welcome, and welcome to the site!  That seek time would be very minimal (hence the capitalization above lol) but even then I don't think there would be any, but I suppose it could depend on the nature of the change you're making and how you implemented it.